# Checking if given set forms basis for $P_3(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, hamel-basis

The question says whether the polynomials $x^3+2x-4,\ x^3+x^2-3x+1, $and $x^3+5$ generate $P_3(\mathbb{R})$? I did the question in a sneaky way as follows. We already know $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ forms the basis for $P_3(\mathbb{R})$, so it's dimension is $4$. Since the given set contains only $3$ elements, it won't generate $P_3(\mathbb{R})$. But I am not satisfied with my argument. How to find those polynomials which won't get generate by the span of the above set. Any hint. Thanks.

Comment: Just make a $4\times 4$ determinant nonzero, or just stare at it long enough to see, for example, $x^2$ isn't spanned by them

Comment: Why are you not satisfied, though? That is actually a good way to solve it! In fact, that's a more elegant manner of doing things. Using more (theoretical) tools to avoid doing a calculative argument.

Comment: I agree with you but I just wanted to know which polynomials will not get generated by span of the given set.

Comment: In that case, note that you already knew that $\{1, \ldots, x^3\}$ generate the whole space and the given set does not. So you know that one (or more) of $1, \ldots, x^3$ must be non-representable. So now you have to work with some equations to see which one.

Answer (score 1):

One demonstration. Let
$A = x^3+2x-4,$
$B = x^3+x^2-3x+1,$
$C = x^3+5$

You can see the subspace Span{$A,B,C$}∩Span{$1,x,x^2$} is generated by
$D = B-A = x^2-5x+5$, 
$E = B-C = x^2-3x-4$

Similarly, the subspace Span{$A,B,C$}$\cap$Span{$1,x$} is generated by
$F = E-D = 2x-9$,
which is clearly smaller than Span{$1,x$}